# Зачем в типе возвращаемого значения указывать интерфейс

Tags: php

Есть вот такой кусок кода класса

```
public function createCellPhone(): Phone
{
    return new CellPhone();
}
```

И сам интерфейс

```
interface Phone
{
 public function call();
}
```

В createCellPhone указан тип возвращаемого значения интерфейс. Зачем?

Comment: Спросите у автора этого кода, наверное?

Comment: Нашел такое обьяснени: объект должен представлять класс, который реализует данный интерфейс. Но что-то не понятно

Comment: Кому и зачем должен? (Собственно, это тоже нужно спрашивать у автора кода видимо)

Comment: Это означает, что возвращаемое значение должно быть объектом класса, реализующего данный интерфейс. В данном случае у него должна быть функция call().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объявления типов могут использоваться для аргументов функций, возвращаемых функцией значений и для свойств класса. Они используются во время исполнения для проверки, что значение имеет точно тот тип, который для них указан.

В противном случае будет выброшено исключение TypeError... которое разработчик теоретически может перехватить и реализовать другой сценарий обработки для исключительного случая.

Это общее описание...

В вашем тривиальном случае, ясно, что функция гарантированно возвратит нужный тип, поэтому указание возвращаемого типа здесь не что иное, как правило хорошего тона. В любой продвинутой среде разработки, всего лишь взглянув на прототип функции - разработчик сразу же видит, что данная функция гарантированно возвратит требуемый интерфейс..., без исключений!